# Problema con ScrollView en IOS

Tags: mvc, ios, scroll-view

Es mi primera vez en IOS, estoy tratando de agregar un ScrollView dentro de un View que se encuentra contenido en otro View, dicho view y scrollview tienen Constraints en 0 por todos sus lados y me arroja el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que además de imágenes acompañes de código así como de los errores en formato escrito. Puedes encontrar más información en [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro de tu scroll view tienes que meter otro View, (o Stack View, o lo que pretendas usar).

A ese view tienes que añadirle restricciones **(Top,Bottom,Leading,Trailing)** al **Content Layout Guide** de tu ScrollView. Y después añade restricciones de **EqualWidth y EqualHeight** respecto al **Frame Layout Guide**